# AWS Cli list IPAddess and name tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I list ipaddress and name tag using aws cli 
`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress[*]" --output table`

Gives me the list of ipaddess but I need IP Address AND Name Tag.

Please help.

Comment: You should check out the examples on [jmespath.org](http://jmespath.org/examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{privateIP:PrivateIpAddress, tags:Tags[*]}"
```

you can add the `table` output if needed but visibility is not so good if you have multiple tags

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{privateIP:PrivateIpAddress, tags:Tags[*]}" \
--output table
```

the output will be

```
----------------------------
|     DescribeInstances    |
+--------------------------+
|         privateIP        |
+--------------------------+
|  172.xx.x.xx             |
+--------------------------+
||          tags          ||
|+--------------+---------+|
||      Key     |  Value  ||
|+--------------+---------+|
||  Name        |  xxxxx  ||
||  Autobuild   |  xxxxx  ||
||  Environment |  xxxxx  ||
|+--------------+---------+|
```

Comment: If you need private-ip and tag['Name'] in one line ```aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddresses[0].PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value| [0]]' --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:environment,Values=production" --output text```